# I created a graph in ZedGraph how can i make the Graph size bigger like 1920X1080?

Tags: c#

When im saving the graph now to the hard disk the file size is: 284x262 290kb
When im trying to put the graph the bmp file from the hard disk on a pdf document it's ver small.
If i stretch it manualy on the pdf it's losing the resolution and looks bad you can't even read anything on the graph.

I want somehow to keep the graph resolution i mean quality and sharpness but make it's size bigger like 1920x1080.

This is the code im using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ZedGraph;
using Extracting_Frames;

namespace Lightnings_Extractor
{
    public partial class RGB_Form : Form
    {
        int framesLength;

        public RGB_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
            zedGraphControl1.ClientSize = this.Size;
            framesLength = Form1.list_of_histogramsR.Count;
        }

        public RGB_Form(List<long[]> Histograms)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
            zedGraphControl1.ClientSize = this.Size;
            framesLength = Histograms.Count;
            CreateGraph_GradientByZBars(zedGraphControl1, Histograms);
        }

        private void CreateGraph_GradientByZBars(ZedGraphControl z1, List<long[]> HistoGramList)
        {
            GraphPane myPane = z1.GraphPane;
            if (myPane != null)
            {
                myPane.CurveList.Clear();
                myPane.GraphObjList.Clear();
                myPane.Title.Text = "Simple Moving Average By :  " + Form1.percentage + "%";
                myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Frame Number";
                myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Value";


                myPane.XAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = false;
                myPane.XAxis.Scale.MinAuto = false;
                myPane.YAxis.Scale.MaxAuto = false;
                myPane.YAxis.Scale.MinAuto = false;

                myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
                myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = 255; //framesLength;
                myPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
                myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = framesLength;// 255;

                PointPairList R = new PointPairList();
                PointPairList G = new PointPairList();
                PointPairList B = new PointPairList();

                for (int i = 0; i <  HistoGramList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 3154)
                    {
                        double z = 0;
                        double yy = 0;
                        long[] g = HistoGramList[i];
                            for (int f = 0; f < g.Length; f++)
                            {
                                double x = f;
                                yy = g[f];
                                R.Add(x, yy, z);
                            }
                    }
                }

                LineItem myCurveRed = myPane.AddCurve("Original Signal",
                   R, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
                z1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
                z1.AxisChange();
                z1.SaveAs(@"ZedRgb.bmp");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Near the end of the code i added:

```
z1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
```

But it didn't change anything still the size of the file on the hard disk is: 284x262

How can i change the graph size and save it to the hard disk without losing quality on 1920x1080 ?
When im using the graph on my program i did it will be on full screen and the graph is big full screen but when im saving it to the hard disk it's very small.

EDIT: I just saw now that on the Form that i added the zedgraph control the form size is 300x300 but the zedgraph control size is 284x262 and to make it full screen i changed the ZedGraph control Dock property to Fill.

So the size in the designer of the ZedGraph control is realy 284x262 how can i change it then in runtime code if i want to save it to my hard disk as 1920x1080 without change the size on the designer ?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the ZedGraph control from Dock Fill to Dock None

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest replacing the line

> z1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);

with

> this.size = new Size(1920,1080);

I'd be interested to know if it works. If it doesn't, another possibile solution might be to add
the line

> this.size = new Size(1920,1080);

before the line

> zedGraphControl1.ClientSize = this.Size;